# Show uib-popover while stopping propagation

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I have clickable rows repeated in Angular, with a clickable popover if you click the contents of a particular cell, like so:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="time in vm.times" ng-click="vm.goToTime(time.id)">
        <td>
            <abbr ng-click="popoverItem=time" 
                  uib-popover-template="'/app/partials/popover.html'" 
                  popover-trigger="click">{{ time.name }}</abbr>
        </td>
        <td>{{time.date}}</td>
        <td>{{time.user}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The idea being, if you click the row, you go to the time details page, but if you click the name in column 1, you get the popover. Except clicking the popover will propagate to clicking the row. How do I prevent this?

Comment: you need to pass `$event` to the click function `vm.goToTime($event, time.id)` -  and in your controller - detect the target element that was clicked and decide what to do

Comment: just what i needed, thanks.